# Slackware, installing Flash and Chrome

Tags: software-installation, chrome, slackware, adobe-flash

I'm having trouble installing flash and chrome. When I download the sources, there are no installers for the packages. All I get is a few folders and .so files. Is there anything out there which shows how to get the latest version of flash via Slackware, or a package manager which has this or something?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Slackware DVD. Open the "extra" folder. You'll find a few Slackbuild files there, including flash player and google chrome.

For chrome, read the Readme files in its folder.

For flash, execute the Slackbuild file on its folder. It'll automatically download and build the .txz files in /tmp.

Now, install the files using:

```
installpkg /tmp/the-flash-player-package.txz
```